# .Net Core - Error when starting app on azure

Tags: azure

I just created a new Web Api on VS for mac OSX. After deploying it to azure, I get the error code `0x80004005 : 8000808c`. What am I doing wrong? the error is very unclear and there's no useful logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` version 2.0.6. I rolled it back to 2.0.0 and worked fine.

**Edit1:**
The deployment of the 2.0.6 package finished an hour ago

Comment: I can't find the github thread now, but I think I read something went sideways with the 2.0.6 release and they're going to re-deploy. Might just try it again. I've been running with 2.0.5 since it relased (Jan 9, 2018) without issues.

Comment: More info here:
https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/476

And here
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.6.md#windows-server-hosting-bundle-dotnetcore206-windowshostingexe-does-not-contain-the-updated-aspnetcore-runtimepackagestore